# Smart computer tic-tac-toe move selection in C

Tags: c, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I'm sure many of you are tired of seeing tic tac toe questions, but I'd appreciate any insight as to why this part doesn't function as intended.

The rest of the code works great, but right here, the computer doesn't make its move, instead it just re-displays the board and goes back to the user's move.

I verified that the user and computer marks are carried over to the function, but the selection process isn't working. It defaults to the for loop, continuing to the other functions from there, but it still doesn't assign the computer's mark.

I already have code elsewhere that makes sure the board isn't full before being sent over to the next move.

Thank you

```
void cmove(char umark, char cmark)
{
    int i=0;
    if((board[4] == NULL))
    {
        board[4] == cmark;
        DisplayBoard();
        cwin(umark , cmark);
    }
    if((board[0] != NULL) && (board[1] != NULL) && (board[2] != NULL) && (board[3] != NULL) && (board[4] == umark) && (board[5] != NULL) &&
       (board[6] != NULL) && (board[7] != NULL) && (board[8] != NULL))
       {
           board[0]= cmark;
           DisplayBoard();
           cwin(umark ,cmark);
       }
    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        if(board[i] == NULL)
        {
            board[i] == cmark;
            DisplayBoard();
            cwin(umark, cmark);
            i=9;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried debugging it to find out which code paths are actually executed? If the application behaves differently than expected, you should first try to debug your program and find out why it does so.

Comment: What are all those `NULL`s? Is your board an array of pointers? Please make sure you have full compiler warnings enabled, might turn up something else.

Comment: `board[4] == cmark;` is a mistake, which the compiler should have warned you of. Also `board[i] == cmark;`. Please change `==` to `=`.

Comment: Oh man, can't believe I put double, I've been coding too long.

Comment: The NULL is checking if is assigned there yet. Using this elsewhere to make sure the user selects an empty slot works.

Comment: @C.NGL `NULL` is a pointer value, not an `int` or `char` value (you didn't show what `board` is)..

Comment: Based on the assignments (if they get fixed as others have suggested), `board` is probably `char board[10]` (e.g.). So, most of your (e.g) `board[3] != NULL` in your `if`s should be `board[3] != 0` The `==` vs `=` with `-Wall` would have been flagged as "statement with no effect"

Comment: "I've been coding too long." But not long enough to routinely enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: As in I'm tired and making stupid mistakes. I am still a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comparison and not an assignment:

```
 board[i] == cmark;
```

You have a similar problem in the first conditional block `board[4] == cmark;`

Turn on all the warnings your compiler can muster to catch this sort of mistake.

Comment: Can't believe I made that stupid mistake. The code still favors the for loop though, which I'm not sure why.

Comment: I was able to fix it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
board[4] == cmark;
```

This is comparison and has no effect. Your intent was to assign instead:

```
board[4] = cmark;
```